# Печать множества документов DOCX, лежащих на сервере

Tags: php, печать, docx

Имеется система на PHP, позволяющая генерировать одностраничные документы .docx (путем перезаписи файла document.xls с последующей упаковкой в docx), после этого отправляет их через curl на регистрацию в СЭД, получает рег. номер (дописывается в колонтитул) и уже с номером сохраняется на сервер в том же docx и ждет печати.
То есть по итогам работы на сервере в папке лежит множество  одностраничных файлов docx.

Собственно, вопрос: как можно отправить их все на печать, желательно одной кнопкой , используя принтер клиента, то есть, используя систему печати того компа, за которым сидит юзер.
Склейка всех файлов на сервере в один решила бы проблему, однако, как реализовать такое на PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы их (документы) генерируете сами, то значит можно и сгенерировать копии в **HTML** виде. Затем эту копии можно открывать в новом окне с помощью javascript сохраняя ссылку на это окно и уже по этой ссылке вызывать печать. Для этого вам понадобятся две js функции:

- window.open()
- window.print()

ps.

Сам такого не делал но подозреваю что вполне может получится.

и только что пришел второй вариант: все полученные копии (в HTML виде) склеить вместе и напечатать за один раз.

Comment: Немного не то, нам нужно печатать не то, что мы сгенерировали, а те файлы, которые были сгенерированы, отпарвлены и получены после регистрации в СЭД с рег. номером, а получаем мы оттуда именно docx

Comment: А вам странным не кажется что получаете его вы, а печать должна произойти на клиентском принтере? Что бы напечатать файл его сначала получить надо, если печать из браузера значит нужна HTMLка, а иначе (если не HTML) использовать стороннюю программу, догадайтесь какую...

есть конешно общий вариант но это на уровне философии: найти какой нибудь плагин для браузера который умеет делать то что вы хотите.